# PHP increment variable with glob

Tags: php

New to PHP...searched the manual, just don't understand how to put it all together. I'm trying to go through a folder and display each html file as it's contents...that part works. I can't figure out how to change a div id incrementally.

This code works for displaying the what I want I just need unique id's in my divs.

```
$dir = realpath('./path/to/folder/of_files/');
foreach (glob($dir .'/*.html') as $page){
   $div = file_get_contents($page);  
   echo ("<div class=\"interface\" id=\"ID_$id\">$div</div>");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$id` is just some integer you can stick an `$id++;` somewhere...

```
$id = 1;
$dir = realpath('./path/to/folder/of_files/');

foreach (glob($dir .'/*.html') as $page){
   $div = file_get_contents($page);  
   echo ("<div class=\"interface\" id=\"ID_$id\">$div</div>");
   $id++;
}
```

Comment: That worked, I had actually had tried something close but it was just incrementing a number after the content of each div. i had  `...</div>") .$id++;` didn't think to add it on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$dir = realpath('./path/to/folder/of_files/');
$id = 1;
foreach (glob($dir .'/*.html') as $page)
{
   $div = file_get_contents($page);  
   echo ("<div class=\"interface\" id=\"ID_{$id}\">$div</div>");
   $id++; //this is just... $id = $id + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can auto increment using foreach's AS syntax.

```
$dir = realpath('./path/to/folder/of_files/');
foreach (glob($dir .'/*.html') as $id => $page)
{
   $div = file_get_contents($page);  
   echo ("<div class=\"interface\" id=\"ID_{$id}\">$div</div>");
}
```

Note that you may want to increment $id in the 'echo' statement if you don't want $id to start at 0.